# Hotkeys to change viewport (Maya preset) won't work, why?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I'm using Maya presets. The hotkeys don't seem to work ether in 3D or Quad view.

It doesn't really bother me in 3D View but it's a problem in quad as I can't seem to change my *Top Ortho* view to *Back Ortho* view to adjust for my reference image.

Keybindings show that I should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad Number</kbd> key, but it doesn't work, I unlocked the view-ports under "Display" and nothing happens.

When I tried it under Blender default settings it worked perfectly.
Also I tried this on two separate computers with different scenes, same result.

I'm a beginner in Blender.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Hj1.jpg

[image]

Comment: Did you change or customize any other hot keys manually? It may be a conflict with other key combination, or it may well be a bug in the Maya Preset, those are not as well maintained/tested as the default one.

Comment: Mr Zak, you were correct! Pressing numbers instead of numpad worked! Please retype that as an answer so i can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works as expected, it's just that the keybindings assume <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> should be pressed in order to activate front ortho view according to the Maya interaction preset (*not* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>).

[image: screenshot of maya keybinding]

If numbers from Numpad were expected it would be visible from this setup.